# Save a DB model in the rails console while looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console

Using the rails console:

I am trying to pull data for a column called 'URL' in a loop, and change a substring within the URL string.  I then want to save it back into the DB for good, here is the simple code:

```
a = Advertiser.where(:name => 'Groupon').first
feeds = Feed.where(:advertiser_id => a.id).all.each { |f| f.url.sub('100', "400"); f.save! }
```

I am not sure why doing the above in the rails console works.  I go and query the DB, and none of the values I expect to change have been modified.  When I run the above, it displays a bunch of values for each record in the DB, but not the modified values.

What am I doing wrong?  (thank you in advance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In rails there is a huge difference between sub and sub!. Where sub works on the string, and returns the 'subed' string, but doesn't actually change the original string, sub! changes the original string in place. So you should use the second version, the sub! in order to have your object changed!

The 'all' is also not necessary, the each already loops through your objects

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and will try later tonight.